# Xcode Help (C) : Console disappears and gives no output

Tags: c, console, xcode6

I am very new to the C programming language and programming in general. I tried to create a simple program that starts at 99 and decreases by 3 until 0. This program also must be able to output "Found one!" when the integer is divisible by 5. Thanks, any help is appreciated!

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 100; i < -1; i -= 3) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if (i % 5 == 0) {
            printf("Found one!\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are having? (In other words, you haven't actually asked a question yet. :-) ) What have you done to debug this? What was the expected output? What output did you get? If you edit your question to include this information, others will be able to help you better (and you'll probably learn a lot yourself too.)

Comment: @c45207 OP kind of asked already: `program that starts at 99 and decreases by 3 until 0`, `output "Found one!" when the integer is divisible by 5`

Comment: a compiler will raise two warnings about unused parameters (the argc and argv) suggest: int main(void)

Comment: this line: 'for (i = 100; i < -1; i -= 3) {' should be: 'for (i = 99; i > 0; i -= 3) {'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#include <stdio.h>  //For printf function
#include <stdlib.h> //For system function

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    int i;

    for (i = 99; i >= 0; i -= 3) {
           //^^    ^^ Changed Condition
           //|i assigned to 99
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) {
                     //^^^^^^^^^Also check that it's not true with 0
            printf("Found one!\n");
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a nice day as well. You don't know how happy you just made me with your help, it means a lot. I'll be sure to check the link and mark your comment as the answer.

Comment: @KyleTweak Not the comment, you have to mark the answer as accepted, with checking the mark to the left from my answer